# How to generate a random string in Rational Performance tester?

Tags: performance-testing, rational-performance-test

I want to do performance testing using rational performance tester where most input fields in the test are unique, so I have to generate random values to use it during run time. I don't want to use excel.
Can any one help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in data source - Random Number. The substitution wizard provides option to set minimum and maximum values.

The Random Number source can be found using Substitute->Select Data Source and then following the options in screenshot below:
[image: Screenshot for Random Number data source]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want a string not a random number, is there any way??

Comment: Ah! In that case, you'll have to write Java custom code. The RPT [knowledge center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMMM5_9.1.1/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.common.doc/topics/textndteswcc.html) has the procedure as well as samples that you could refer.